# Searching in lucene indexes is bit slow when using azure library for lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net, azure-storage

I am using Azure Library for Lucene.Net to index and search data.
My webrole indexes data, below code is used to create indexes:

```
AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AzureStorageConnectionString")), pIndexDir);

IndexWriter indexWriter  = indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, null, findexExists, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
indexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(10.0);
indexWriter.SetUseCompoundFile(false);
indexWriter.SetMaxMergeDocs(10000);
indexWriter.SetMergeFactor(100);
```

And my same webrole searches for the data, below code is used to search in indexes.

```
 AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AzureStorageConnectionString")), pIndexToSearch);
 IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(azureDirectory,true);
```

As by default AzureDirectory stores cache in local temp folder, above code will use local tenp folder to cache.

In service definition file I have not configured local storage resource for the web role.

I am using Small VM role size.

My problem is when i am searching for any word the **search results are not retrieved as fast as they should be..it is bit slow.**

I am not sure if I am missing any configuration...or do I need to create an AzureDirectory with a RAMDirectory pointed to the blob storage for searching so that it would be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creating an AzureDirectory with a RAMDirectory pointed to the blob storage for faster searching. I can load all indexes in RAMDir as my indexes size is small enough to be loaded in RAMDir.Also I using singleton so that same instance of index searcher is user and reloading the RAMDir at specific intervals so that it has latest updated indexes.

Comment: Any chance of sharing a sample code or blog post of detailed instructions?
Thanks

Comment: hey jalchr, As the index size is not huge in my scenario I am loading whole indexes in RAMDir using below code

AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AzureStorageConnectionString")), pIndexDir); 

for writer
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, null, isNew, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

for index searcher,
_contentSearcher = new IndexSearcher(azureDirectory, true);

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a version that uses the Azure shared Cache (Preview version). This will be closer to the speed of the RAM directory but also has the added advantage that it is shared between instances...

https://github.com/ajorkowski/AzureDataCacheDirectory